# How to assign an edited dataset to a new variable in R?

Tags: r

The title might be misleading but I have the scenario here:

```
half_paper <- lapply(data_set[,-1], function(x) x[x==0]<-0.5)
```

This line is supposed to substitute 0 for 0.5 in all of the columns except the first one.

Then I want to take    half_paper  and put it into here where it would rank all of the columns except the first one in order.:

```
prestige_paper <-apply(half_paper[,-1],2,rank)
```

But I get an error and I think that I need to somehow make     half_paper  into a data set like data_set.

Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue 'This line is supposed to substitute `0` for `0.5` in all of the columns except the first one' can be remedied by placing another line in your anonymous function. The gets operator `<-` returns the value of whatever is on the right hand side, so your `lapply` was returning a value of `0.5` for each column. To remedy this, another line can be added to the function that returns the modified vector.

It's also worth noting that `lapply` returns a list. `apply` was substituted in for lapply in this case for consistency, but `plyr::ddply` may suit this specific need better.

```
half_mtcars <- apply(mtcars[, -1], 2, function(x) {x[x == 0] <- .5;return(x)})

prestige_mtcars_tail <- apply(half_mtcars, 2, rank)

prestige_mtcars <- cbind(mtcars[,1, drop = F], prestige_mtcars_tail)
```